# Is it better to develop on Mac or Windows?

Tags: windows, macos

I have noticed a lot of developer these day developing on Macs. I have never use one for an extended period of time or to develop. I was thinking of investing in one for programming purposes but don't have sufficient knowledge in pros/cons of developing on Mac OS X or Windows. I was hoping you all could help provide guidance as to which platform is better suited for development?

Thanks in advance :)

**No Flame Wars Please, hoping we can keep this civilized. :)

Comment: Develop what?  Web apps, native, java?

Comment: This should be community wiki

Comment: You'd probably get less subjective answers if you gave more details regarding what you kind of applications you want to develop or perhaps the language, or maybe if you want a general comparison of the tools (again that's likely to be subjective).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to develop and who it is for, if you want a Mac application develop on the Mac, if you want a Windows application then use windows.

If you want both then see "Java"

Comment: +1, though if you want both with the same code base and interface, see "bad idea".

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what platform you're developing for and what your personal preferences are.

Personally, I prefer a Mac as it allows me to develop for Mac, iPhone, Mono, Python, Ruby and if I want to switch out and do "Corporate" .NET development, all I need to do is fire up Sun VirtualBox and I can have whatever Windows boxes I need running.

Linux would be a close second to the Mac only because you lose the ability to develop iPhone and Mac applications on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

That's depend on your audience.

For mainstream purposes go with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As others said before: It depends on what you want to do. I'm a full time .Net developer on Windows and I really really like the .Net platform for software development. Visual Studio is in my opinion the best IDE I have ever used. So from my point of view Windows is a great development platform.

In my spare time, I'm a 100% Mac user. Using a Mac you get the Unix-feeling, but without the hassle to manage a Linux system and with a much nicer GUI. So if you want to develop stuff, which is not bound to Windows (Django/Python, Rails/Ruby, ...), OS X is a nice environment to do so.

Or as a very subjective summary: Windows is the best platform to gain money and a Mac is cool! ;-)